# Eclipse not compiling at all

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, javac

I was working on a project and suddenly after sometime Ecplise stopped compiling files for me. 
I even tried creating a new simple class in a new package and tried to run it but I always get the error message.

Error: Could not find or load main class xxxx.main

The simple class I am trying to compile is

```
package Kapitel_11;

public class ovning_11_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] a = new double[50];

        for (int i = 1; i > a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = 1/i;
        }
        for (int i = 1;i > a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);

        }
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

I tried reinstalling Eclipse and java developer kit. I even tried to clean the project and refresh it.
My Eclipse version is 2018-09 (4.9.0) and build id: 20180917-1800.

My Java Developer kit version is Java 8 update 191.

And I am running MacOS 10.14.1.

Thanks for your time and hope you can find me a solution.

Comment: `ovning_11_2 ` is not `xxxx.main`

Comment: I mean the class name by xxxx. :) Sorry if it was hard to understand.

Comment: Yes you are trying to run another class that is not found in the code.

Comment: No I mean that the error accrue for every class, not only this one.

Comment: Yes, It's trying to run a class that is not found.

Comment: try this? http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs302/labs/EclipseTutorial/Step_04.html

Comment: Your sample code shows the class `Kapitel_11.ovning_11_2`, not `xxxx.main`. Build or compile errors (which are shown in the _Problems_ view) might prevent compiling and executing the code.

Answer (score 0):

At the run button in Eclipse, from the drop down menu Select.

> Run As >> Java Application